# Convergence of the alternating series

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

if $(a_n)$ be a sequence such that $a_i \geq a_j\;, \forall i < j$ and converges to 0, alternating series defined by $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n} (-1)^{n+1}a_n$ converges.  I went through the proof, and a similar argument can be said about $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n} (-1)^{n}a_n$.

Basically, my question is, if the above condition regarding the sequence holds, can we say that the series $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n} (-1)^{n}a_n$ also converges ?

Comment: If $a_i$ are monotonically non-increasing and going to 0, then yes, the alternating series converges. Your question is a bit unclear: what is the "above condition"? Please fix your formatting to clarify.

Comment: I don't understand your question. First, you tell use that you are aware of an argument that proves that the series $\sum_n(-1)^na_n$ converges, but right after you as us whether it converge or not.

Comment: $\sum_{n} (-1)^n a_n = - \sum_{n} (-1)^{n+1} a_n$, so the first converges iff the second does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n} (-1)^{n}a_n$$ converges, then $$\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n} (-1)^{n+1}a_n$$ must converge to $$-\displaystyle \sum\limits_{n} (-1)^{n}a_n$$

Note that for the alternating convergent series we also need $$a_n \ge 0 $$

Comment: Regarding the last point: the sequence is monotonically decreasing, so it conerges. If it doesn't converge to $0$, then no need for that test, the series diverges trivially. If it does converge to 0, then it is non-negative.